# Temp table was not dropped

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I try to drop my temporary table I got an error:

> Database id 65, page (1:4825) is marked restorepending, which may indicate disk corruption. To recover from this this state, perform a restore

My table name is `temp_f`.

I used a drop query like this

```
Drop table temp_f
Drop table #temp_f
Drop table ##temp_f
```

But I still get the same error.

Comment: There's something wrong with your database. This question belongs to the dba site.

Comment: Simply bouncing the SQL service should cause the tempdb database to be rebuilt, from scratch, from the model db.

Comment: @JasonA.Long this isn't an actual temp table.

Comment: There's a world of difference between a regular table, a temp table, and a Global Temp table